# OrientDB For Loop

Tags: orientdb

I Want To create single query with for loop

For example I have table 1

```
[id , Name]
[ 1 , X1]
[ 2 , X2]
[ 3 , X3]
```

And Seconde Table

```
[id, Name]
[ 5 , Y5]
[ 6 , Y6]
[ 7 , Y7]
```

All I want is to have new table with followin data

```
[NewName]
[X1-Y5]
[X1-Y6]
[X1-Y7]
[X2-Y5]
[X2-Y6]
[X1-Y7]
[X3-Y5]
[X3-Y6]
[X3-Y7]
```

I am failing to create this , I am able to this with only fisrt or alst row of table using first() and last() commands

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if I got it right: are you trying to create edges between the two classes? Or are you trying to do some kind of join?

Comment: Not , this is a simlpe SQL table

Answer (score 0):

To get the combination you want in a new table try this javascript function:

```
var g = orient.getGraph();
var table1 = g.command("sql","select from table1");
var table2 = g.command("sql","select from table2");

for(i = 0; i < table1.length; i++)
{
  for(j = 0; j < table2.length; j++)
  {
    g.command("sql","insert into table3(newName) values ('"+ table1[i].getRecord().field("name") +" - "+ table2[j].getRecord().field("name") +"')")
  }
}
```

you can call it in SQL like in this way:

```
select function_name()
```

in this way you have a sort of join table, if this is your intent is not the correct way to because there is no JOIN in OrientDB, instead you can use Edge, Link ...

In case you're looking for how to do what you want, you can try this javascript function:

```
var g = orient.getGraph();
var table1 = g.command("sql","select from table1");
var table2 = g.command("sql","select from table2");

for(i = 0; i < table1.length; i++)
{
  for(j = 0; j < table2.length; j++)
  {
    g.command("sql","create edge connection from "+ table1[i].getId() +" to "+ table2[j].getId() +"")
  }
}
```

as before, you can call it in SQL like in this way:

```
select function_name()
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: I am trying to do this with one query only